# angular ng repeat disable all items except first item

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a list of items. Each item is in div. i want to show only first item enable except others shows disabled.

**AngularJs**

```
angular.module('example', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [1,2,3];
});
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="example" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you tried my answer?

Answer (score 8):

simply by using [$first](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) attribute:

```
<div ng-app="example" ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-disabled="!$first">{{item}}</div>
 </div>
```

beware: ng-disabled works with form elements. see [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) for details.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this using $first.

```js
 angular.module('example', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [1,2,3];
      });
```

```html
    

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

    <div ng-app="example" ng-controller="myCtrl">
         <div ng-repeat="item in items"><span ng-if="$first">{{item}}</span>
<span ng-if="!$first">do whatever you want with this item {{item}} </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this snippet.

```js
angular.module('example', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function Ctrl($scope) {
      $scope.items = [1,2,3];
});
```

```css
.disable {
  color: #ccc;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="example" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <b>First way</b>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
    <input ng-disabled="$index != '0'" type="text" value="do whatever you want with this item {{item}}"/>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <b>Second way</b>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input ng-disabled="!$first" type="text" value="do whatever you want with this item {{item}}"/>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <b>Third way</b>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span ng-class="{'disable': !$first}">do whatever you want with this item {{item}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is with input type and other is with class so if some one has disable from console then it will not work. but ya third one helped me lot thanks for it

Comment: @Nitin: So still you're getting any problem?

Comment: regarding class i was getting then i did one more condition in my page. i put it below what i did

Comment: i posted as answer

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-app="example" ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class='{disable:!$first}' >{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using disable class we can only apply disable css if someone did change from console then it will break so i did as followed

```
<div ng-app="example" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'disabled-me': !($index==0)}">
    <span ng-click="($index!=0) ? false : xyx(item)">{{item}}</span></div>
</div>
```

And in css

```
.disabled-me,.disabled-me span{color: #777 !important;cursor: default;}
```